# if we have safek dioraisa l'chumrah, why do we need safek d'rabanan l'kulah?

Tags: safek, deorayta

If we already know safek dioraisa l'chumrah, why do we need  safek d'rabanan l'kulah?

Comment: Obvious question to ask of you, here - The 2 ideas are not in conflict with each other. A *safek* means that there's a doubt about if you should do something one way or another - in most cases a "yes" / "no" decision. All these rules are stating is that if it's a Torah mitzvah, you follow the stricter opinion; if it's a Rabbinical mitzvah, follow the lenient one. Someone has to tell you that rule b/c people may assume in specific cases or as a general rule that Rabbinical mitzvot should follow the more stringent rule.

Comment: Hava amina lo sasur makes it into a dioraisa for this. Ka mashma lan we don't say this.

Comment: @user6591 You may want to translate the above for benefit of other M.Y. readers. Your ref. to *lo sasur* seems correct. If you can translate and link the source for that, I think you have an answer. Though, admittedly, the question seems vague, as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The reason we need to have both rules is because one does not follow logically from the other. Given just *safeik deoraita l'chumra* we could potentially also say *safeik derabanan l'chumra*. Likewise vice-versa.

Comment: A good proof to this is we have discussions about "Divrei Soferim Lechumra/Lekula" and "Divrei Kabbala Lechumra/LeKula".

Comment: @DoubleAA Where are those statements listed? Shabbat Shalom.